# MYSQL syntax for inserting data to a table from another one which are not same form

Tags: mysql

It could be obvious but since I don't have any experience I cannot figure out how to do. Here is the question; say I have table2 with fields id,name, time, price and explanation.Also, there is an other table1 which has name, time and price. I want to insert data from table1 if price is higher than some threshold, while doing so as an explanation I want "The price is above threshold". Can anyone suggest me a way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`name`, `time`, `price`, `explanation`)
SELECT `name`, `time`, `price`, 'The price is above threshold'
FROM `table1`
WHERE `price` > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
[INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
SELECT ...
[ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
```

With `INSERT ... SELECT`, you can quickly insert many rows into a table from one or many tables. For example:

INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
   SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
   FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;

The following conditions hold for a `INSERT ... SELECT` statements: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: But this only insert existing table and not create explanation.

Comment: You didn't say you wanted to create a new table in your question.  You said there there was another table.  I suggest you revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT table1 (name, time, price)
SELECT name, time, price
FROM table2
WHERE price > 120
```

Comment: There is no id in this code also how can I add explanation. This will only produce exactly same table, except prices are above 120. What I need is to create a table like above plus two additional field one is id the other one is explanation. Also, I want explanation as this sentence: "The price is above threshold" if price is higher

Answer (score 0):

You use an INSERT statement and list the fields you wish to insert into, followed by the SELECT statement you are going to use to populate the fields with.  Here's a link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO insert_tablename (field1, field2, field3)

SELECT  field1, field2, field3

< The rest of your select statement >
```